# Core Data - cannot store two separate entities

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have Core Data working correctly (loading, saving) with one entity called THSettings.

However, I want to create another unrelated Core Data entity called THDetails.

When I create another entity in the same xcdatamodeld file it gives me this error when running the app: "The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store".

So I removed that entity and created another xcdatamodeld file for the new entity and now it gives this error: 
"*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'NSFetchRequest could not locate an NSEntityDescription for entity name 'THDetails''"

Can anyone please tell me why this does not work? I should be able to save multiple unrelated entities...

Here is the code to load THDetails:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)loadSavedNotes {
    THAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"THDetails"];
    NSMutableArray *detailsList = [[moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
    NSLog(@"%d", [detailsList count]);
    return detailsList;
}
```

Here is the code to load THSettings:

```
THAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"THSettings"];
NSMutableArray *settingsList = [[moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];


// ... process it
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a model that defines *all* your entities. If you add an additional
entity to a model, you have two options:

- Just add the new entity to the existing model. In this case you have to *remove* the app
  from the Simulator or device before running the new code to start with a new fresh
  database that is compatible with the changed model. This is usually done during development,
  when there is no need to preserve data. OR:
- Create a model *version* and add the "lightweight migration" options when the Core Data
  stack is initialized. In this case both the old and the new model are copied into the 
  application bundle, and Core Data can (under some conditions) *migrate* the old database
  to a new database. This would be done if an update is made for an already distributed app,
  and you want that the data is preserved. 
  "Lightweight migration" works for simple changes in the model, such as adding a new
  entity.
  See ["Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration Programming Guide"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004399-CH1-SW1) for more information.

Comment: I tried the first option and it works as required. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You problem is that when you change the model, the persistent store (i.e. sqlite database) becomes incompatible with the changed model.
There are several ways to handle this type of error, for example to perform lightweight migration.

Easiest way is to simply recreate persistent store:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSURL *storeURL = ...;
_persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] 
                     initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

// if storeCoordinator can't open at storeURL for some reason
if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType 
                                               configuration:nil 
                                                         URL:storeURL 
                                                     options:nil 
                                                       error:&error]) 
{
    // if there is a database - it means it's the problem - delete it
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:storeURL.path]) 
    {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:nil];

        // if storeCoordinator still can't open a database, means some other error
        if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType 
                                                       configuration:nil 
                                                                 URL:storeURL 
                                                             options:nil 
                                                               error:&error]) 
        {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Database structure has changed. All information had been erased"
                                                             message:nil
                                                            delegate:nil
                                                   cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                    otherButtonTitles:nil, nil;
        [alertView show];
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, if everything else (like migration) fails, it is probably better to recreate the store than letting the app crash.